# Limit calculation - Arithmetic

Tags: calculus, limits

I've the following question for homework.

Find the wrong operations between `a` and `d` and explain why.
[image]

Currently i think that the following operations are wrong:

- `a` is wrong since the number `1` in the denominator is deleted without doing so in the numerator.
- `d` is wrong since $\infty - \infty \neq 0$

What's your take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d is absolutely correct. The limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac x4-\frac x4\right)$$
is equal to the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} 0$$ which is equal to $0$.

You are correct, $a$ is indeed wrong, but all other equalities are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The result seems to be wrong $$\frac{x^3}{(2 x+1)^2}=\frac{x^3}{4 x^2+4 x+1}$$ Perform the long division and get $$\frac{x}{4}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{16 x}+\cdots$$ All of that makes $$\frac{x^3}{(2 x+1)^2}-\frac x4=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{16 x}+\cdots$$ So, for $x\to \infty$, the limit is $-\frac{1}{4}$ and it is apporached from above. You could check it graphing the function.